# Google event tracking code, correct?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I'm trying to track clicks on the submit-button on a form on a page but it's not working.
I'm using this code:

```
    $('#edit-company-questions-submit').submit(function() {
      _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Sales contact');
    });
```

Is this correct or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: That should work. Are you using this code before you have loaded the ga.js?

Comment: Can you make sure the function gets called on submit by adding alert just above _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Sales contact');

Comment: The alert didn't fire. jQuery is working though, I'm using it on other elements. When you press submit, you get a popup box with an ok/error message, maybe that is messing with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap your events in an array if you are using the default async snippet:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Sales contact']);
```

Have a look at the [Event Tracking Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for more examples. Also install the [GADebug extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) to see what events get sent from your page.

Comment: Thank's, I didn't notice that. The code still doesn't work though but it's probably a different reason than this code.